# How to install Ktlint in windows

Tags: android, windows, ktlint

**What I am trying to do**: I am trying to install ktlint on windows locally

**What I tried**:

Used below command in command prompt

```
curl -sSLO https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/releases/download/0.38.1/ktlint && chmod a+x ktlint
```

Also tried above command by using in below steps in link

```
https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/
```

**What is happening**: Not able to install in windows.

### ***How to install in windows ?***

Answer (score 4):

I was having trouble installing ktlint for Windows 10. What worked for me was going to the [Releases](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/releases) page, downloading the `ktlint` file, renaming the `ktlint` file to `ktlint.jar` and adding it inside my Android project root folder (in reference to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/400)) (Note: Java must be installed so that the file extension can be recognized), then running `java -jar ktlint.jar --apply-to-idea-project` (in the command line, from the Android project root directory). Then finally I was able to get it to work, resulting in the following text:

```
The following files are going to be updated:

        .\.idea\codeStyles\codeStyleConfig.xml
        .\.idea\codeStyles\Project.xml
        .\.idea\inspectionProfiles\profiles_settings.xml
        .\.idea\inspectionProfiles\ktlint.xml
        .\.idea\workspace.xml

Do you wish to proceed? [y/n]
(in future, use -y flag if you wish to skip confirmation)
y
(updated)

Please restart your IDE
(if you experience any issues please report them at https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint)
```

Without updating the file to have the `.jar` extension and adding `.jar` to the filename command line parameter, I kept getting the following error:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile ktlint`

To run ktlint immediately, run `java -jar ktlint.jar` in the command line (in the directory where the ktlint.jar file resides).

You can install a git hook to automatically check files for style violations on commit by entering the following command in the Command Line (run "ktlint installGitPrePushHook" if you wish to run ktlint on push instead):
`java -jar ktlint.jar installGitPreCommitHook`

But this will only allow you to set hook for your current command line session. If you close out of Command Prompt, the settings will be reset. If you want to have the ktlinter run on every session for your project, you have to add the `java -jar ktlint.jar` command to your project's `.git/hook/pre-commit` file and paste the ktlint.jar file into the `.git/hook` folder as well.

Comment: xargs: ktlint: No such file or directory Error: Unable to access jarfile ktlint.jar

Comment: Need more info on what you are doing. Did you rename the ktlint file to ktlint.jar? Did you run the command in the same file as the ktlint file?

Answer (score 2):

Download the ktlint jar ffile from the [lib](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint) and add it in your project

Run `java -jar ktlint` on the command line

From that point and then `gradlew ktlintCheck` should work